# Defining a Symfony Service Locator

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I want to test my privare service. I saw people recommending to get it with Locator.
I'm trying to do as docs say: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html#defining-a-service-locator
My services.yaml:

```
    App\Tests\ServiceLocators\AuthServiceLocator:
    arguments: !service_locator
        App\Service\AuthManager: '@App\Service\AuthManager'
```

I'm getting:

```
Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\LoaderLoadException : "!service_locator" tag only accepts maps of "@service" references in "/var/www/api/src/../config/services.yaml" in /var/www/api/src/../config/services.yaml (which is being imported from "/var/www/api/src/Kernel.php").
```

/var/www/api/vendor/symfony/config/Loader/FileLoader.php:173

**Do Symfony docs contain invalid yaml or what is going on?**

**My attempts to work around:**
If I define tag this way, I'm getting no error:

```
    App\Tests\ServiceLocators\AuthServiceLocator:
    tags: ['container.service_locator']
    arguments: 
        App\Service\AuthManager: '@App\Service\AuthManager'
```

But when I run my tests I get:

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException : Invalid definition for service "App\Tests\ServiceLocators\AuthServiceLocator": an array of references is expected as first argument when the "container.service_locator" tag is set.
```

My Locator has this constructor:

```
class AuthServiceLocator
{
public function __construct(public array $handler, public AuthManager $authManager)
{
}
```

I have tried different combinations(only array, only AuthManager), but it wont work

Comment: Maybe you could fix your code formatting in the question?  Right now the indents are all messed up so it is hard to say if it is valid or not.  Using a locator just for testing seems a bit strange to me at least.

Comment: Also, as your first link shows, the AuthServiceLocator constructor must typehint against ContainerInterface

Comment: yeah. if only it worked this way. it wants an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test your private services in a test extending WebTestCase or KernelTestCase you can already get your private services from a specially prepared.

```
class MyTestCase extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function testMyService(): void
    {
        static::bootKernel();
        $myService = static::$container->get(MyService::class);
        // Symfony 5.3+
        $myService = static::getContainer()->get(MyService::class);

        ...
    }
}
```

Notice, that we don't call `$kernel->getContainer()` and instead directly get a container from the test. Internally this will call the following code:

```
static::$container = $container->has('test.service_container') ? $container->get('test.service_container') : $container;
```

The `test.service_container` is basically the locator you are trying to build manually. You can also use the configuration as a reference. See: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/test.php#L46-L56

Comment: thanks. using static context worked for me